# Error in archive_command in Windows 7

Tags: database, postgresql-9.0

I have done these steps:

1. Opened `postgresql.conf`
2. Set these parameters:

   ```
   wal_level = archive
   archive_mode =on
   archive_command = ''copy %p \\\\192.168.1.10\\Archive\\wals\\%f''
   ```

Where 192.168.1.10 is my PC IP address and Archive is a shared folder in D drive.

When I restart postgres service I found the archived files in Archive folder.

That's what I want to do.

But now I  want to store the archived files in another PC having the IP address "192.168.1.41" for that I did these steps:

1. I create a folder Archive and a sub folder WALs within it.
2. make it shareable and full access for every one.
3. update the `archive_command = ''copy %p \\\\192.168.1.41\\Archive\\wals\\%f''` in my PC

Now when I restart the postgres service no archived files are received in remote PC "192.168.1.41".

When I open the `pg_log` folder to see the log file I found the error somthing like:

```
  The failed archive command was: 
     copy pg_xlog\000000010000000000000009 \\192.168.1.41\PGArchivewals\000000010000000000000009
    The referenced account is currently locked out and may not be logged on to.
```

Comment: Please *always* specify the PostgreSQL version you are using.

Comment: @CraigRinger I am using the  9.0  version of PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the firewall on on both the PC(master and slave) and check the permission for the account by which you are accessing the postgres database

Comment: I have check both case firewall on and off but it is not working

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that the PostgreSQL server does not run under your own user account. It runs under the `postgres` user (for PostgreSQL 9.1 and older) or under the `NETWORKSERVICE` user (for PostgreSQL 9.2 and newer).

Neither of these accounts have access to your saved passwords and connections. Nor do they have access to any Active Directory Domain rights your user account might have, as they are local-only accounts.

To use Windows networking (SMB/CIFS) with UNC paths from a service account takes additional configuration, particularly when connecting to an address other than that of your local PC. You will probably need to have a setup script that does a `net use` with a password specified.

It's possible you can add rights on the share on the remote machine so that the `postgres` account can connect by creating a `postgres` account on the remote machine (if one doesn't exist) and making sure it has the same password. This won't work for `NETWORKSERVICE` in 9.2 and won't work on AD domains either.

The "proper" solution would be to change PostgreSQL so it runs under a privileged account with network access rights. This is not excessively difficult, but requires you to edit or create a Windows service and change permissions correctly on the PostgreSQL data directory. If you get it wrong your PostgreSQL install will stop working and may be difficult to fix. For that reason I don't recommend it unless you know Windows services and configuration quite well - in which case you'd already know why what you're trying doesn't work.

A simpler workaround is to use something like FTP to transfer the files between the machines.

Comment: My postgres *version is 9.0* under Windows

Comment: Creating or editing the Windows Service for Postgres isn't terribly difficult. through `pg_ctl` actually.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yep, and `icacls.exe` (newer Windows, don't remember exactly when) or `cacls.exe` (older Windows) for the permissions. Or just the Security tab. In my experience though most Windows users and even many "server admins" have no idea how ACLs and permissions work, which is why I'm hesitant to tell them to just make a domain account, change the permissions on the data dir, and re-register Pg under it with `pg_ctl`.